# Check my Latin (a joke about electrical engineering)

Tags: translation-check

> Ego studeo scientiam computorum. Professor nobis sic explicabat Biot-Savart legem: "*Aqua non incipit exire ex cuppa si parva pars aeris ex spatio circa eam cuppam non venit in eam. Similiter, electricitas non incipit fluere ex electrico fonte si parva pars magnetici campi ex filo metallico non venit in eum electricum fontem. Id est quod Biot-Savart lex dicit.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few points:

- *ego* is unncessary
- *studere* takes a dative object
- What is the base form of *computorum* supposed to be? A frequently found word for "computer" is *computatrum*, in which case you could say *scientia* (or *ars*) *computatrorum*, but you could also say *informatica*. (I have observed in the past that calling informatics "computer science" is akin to calling biology "microscope science," but what can you do...)
- *explicabat*, why imperfect?
- I would prefer the word order *lex Biot-Savart*
- *exire*, a better term for what the water does is *effluere*
- likewise, I think what the air does should be *influere*
- *si ... non* should be *nisi*, and I'd drop the *incipit*, i.e. *non effluit ex cuppa nisi ...*
- *spatio* seems strange to me, I'd simply say *pars aeris, qui circa est, ...*

So to summarize, you might say something like: *Cogita in animo aquam, quae in cuppa continetur: nullo modo effluere potest nisi parva pars aeris, qui circa est, simul in cuppam influit.*

The same considerations apply to the second part about electromagnetism.