# Check my latin (a joke about academia)

Tags: translation-check

> In principio oralis inquistionis technicae electricitatis, professor me rogavit: "*Ergo, collega, didicistine? Praeparavistine pro hac inquistione?*" Ego respondi: "*Non realiter, non.*". Professor mihi tunc dixit: "*Collega, honestas normaliter bona res est, sed non nunc. Ego sedeo hac cathedra ab octava hora ante meridiem sine pausa, meum dorsum me occidit, et mihi non carum est audire quia aliquis qui non praeparavit venit hic.*".

Comment: It would be helpful for you to include a translation and any particular parts you weren't sure about. I definitely feel that *meum dorsum me occidit* is a very English-language idiom, so if you're trying to write something Classical in flavour (as opposed to leaving it as an inside joke for English-speaking Latin readers) I'd find another phrase.

Comment: I'll second @dbmag9's suggestion. Can you say what exactly we're supposed to be looking for? Mere grammar? Stylistic suggestions? Classical v. post-classical differences? It's definitely a pretty literal translation of the English.

Comment: Generally, I commend the translation and the mostly very good Latin, but agree with the other commenters that with more guidance from you, someone could give a more helpful response, depending on what you might want from an answer and what period of Latin you are trying to emulate.   For instance, *quia* only works with later Latin.  As further examples, there are changes in word order that would be more normal for the classical period and changes in some of the word choices, such as *nōn realiter* for what is probably meant as "not really, no" or *prō* for *prō hāc inquīs[ī]tiōne*.

Comment: I closed this question and [the other similar unanswered one](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/17829/79) and [the answered one](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/17818/79) for lack of details. See the comments above for details; they apply to all questions. Please edit to elaborate so that your question contains a clear question and goal!

Comment: Verba Latina intelligō, iocum vērō nōn. Quid technica electricitātis? Inest in fabellā paronomasia?